# How to set up authorization in Google Maps according to the OAuth 2.0 protocol?

Tags: android, google-maps, oauth

I decided to realize in my application on Android access to the user resources to Google Maps according to the OAuth 2.0 protocol. For me it is a new experience, I don't know with what to begin, I didn't find good examples, can be looked for badly therefore I decided to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can read OAuth step from Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2)

Here are the basic steps:

1. Obtain OAuth 2.0 credentials from the Google Developers Console.
2. Obtain an access token from the Google Authorization Server.
3. Send the access token to an API.
4. Refresh the access token, if necessary.